# Compare complexity of two algorithms: Identify Basic Operation applicable for both algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

For an assignment I have to theoretically analyze the complexity of two algorithms (sorting) to compare them. Then I will implement them and try to confirm the efficiency empirically.

Given that, I analyzed both algorithms and I know the efficiency classes but I have a problem identifying the basic operation. There was a hint that we should be careful in choosing a basic operation because it should be applicable for both algorithms. My problem is that I don't really know why I should take the same basic operation for both algorithms.

Pseudocode

Algo1:

```
//sorts given array A[0..n-1]
for i=0 to n-2
  min <- i 
  for j <- i+1 to n-1
    if A[j] < A[min] min <- j
  swap A[i] and A[min]
```

Efficiency: Theta(n^2)

Algo2:

```
//sorts given array with limited range (u,l)
for j = 0 to u-l  D[j] = 0
for i = 0 to n-1 
  D[A[i]-l] = D[A[i]-l]+1
for j=1 to u-l D[j] = D[j-1]+D[j]

for i=n-1 to 0
  j = A[i]-l
  S[D[j]-1] = A[i]
  D[j] = D[j]-1
return S
```

Efficiency Levitin -> Theta(n), Johnsonbaugh -> Theta(n+m) m: distinctable integers in array

So my understanding is that I choose the operation occuring the most as basic operation and I don't see why there is a difference when I choose different basic operations for each algorithm. In the end it doesn't matter because it will lead to the same efficiency class anyway but maybe its important for the empirical analysis (comparing the number of basic operation needed for different input sizes)?

What I plan to do now is to choose assignment as basic operation which is performed 5 times in Algo1 and 6 times in Algo 2 (dependant on the loops of course). Is there a downside to this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical choices for "basic operation" would be to look at number of comparisons, or swaps.

Consider a system with a memory hierarchy, where "hot" items are in cache and "cold" items result in an L2-miss followed by RAM reference, or result in a disk I/O. Then the cache hit cost might be essentially zero, and the basic operation boils down to cost of cache misses, leading to a new expression for time complexity.

Mostly-ordered lists get sorted [more often than you might think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). A stable sort may be more cache-friendly than an unstable sort. If it is easy to reason about how a sort's comparison order interacts with cache evictions, that can lead to a good big-O description of its expected running time.

EDIT: "Reading an element of A[]" seems a fair operation to talk about. Fancier analyses would look at how many "cache miss on A[]" operations happen.

Comment: Thanks! My problem here is that the hint says the basic operation should be applicable to both algorithms. I don't have a comparison/swap in the second algorithm (not that im aware of?)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why "Reading an element of A[]" is a fair operation? I ask because loop 1 and 3 in Algo2 (both from 0 to u-l) are not considered in the efficiency.

Comment: I was just going for something easy, and A[] appears in both. Another operation could be "number of array reads", or, harder to measure, "number of random reads". For example, the "clear to zero" `for j = 0 to u-l  D[j] = 0` writes will stress memory bandwidth, they're relatively easy to do in a performant way. And `for j=1 to u-l D[j] = D[j-1]+D[j]` is very sequential, very cache friendly. But random reads take a *long* time, as they blow out the cache on large problems. So in algo2 I suppose the later `D[j]` reference is the expensive operation to worry about. Profile to verify!